# How to set various option in Leaflet openPopup?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, popup

I want to remove close button in popup of marker. 
How to set option in openPopup() method.
My code is:

```
var mymap = L.map('map1').setView([lat, lng], 13);

var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(mymap);

var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(mymap);
marker.bindPopup(loc_address);

marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {       
     this.openPopup();
});

marker.on('mouseout', function (e) {
     this.closePopup();
});
```

Comment: Hi. You want the x icon not to be visible in the maker popup? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes right I want to hide it.

Comment: You can use css to do that. I posted an answer. Let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to hide the x icon on the marker, you can set the `display` property of the relevant class to `none`. Try using the following code in your css file:

```
.leaflet-popup-close-button {
   display: none; 
}
```

```js
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
  .openPopup();
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.leaflet-popup-close-button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`.openPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#layer-openpopup) method does not expect any option.

It is within the [`.bindPopup`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#layer-bindpopup) method that you can specify options for your Leaflet Popup.

In particular, you should be interested in the [`closeButton`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#popup-closebutton) option:

> Controls the presence of a close button in the popup.

```js
marker.bindPopup(loc_address, {
  closeButton: false
});
```

Comment: how can we write a function to trigger when clicking on the close button?

Comment: Look at the map popupclose event. Feel free to open a new question!